# Ошибка Невозможно применить индексирование через [] к выражению типа "object""

Tags: c#, dapper

Вот код с ошибкой.

```
var List = db.Query<dynamic>("SELECT Name, Type, Parent FROM TreeView Where Level = 1");
foreach (dynamic el in List)
{
   MessageBox.Show(el[0].ToString()); //Выдает ошибку: Невозможно применить индексирование через [] к выражению типа "object""
   MessageBox.Show(el[1].ToString());
   MessageBox.Show(el[2].ToString());
}
```

Как привести el к массиву?
Если обращаюсь вот так - "MessageBox.Show(el.Name.ToString());", то все нормально.
Использую Dapper(ORM).

Comment: Ну так так и обращайтесь. Откуда у объекта из БД индексатор?

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Мне надо именно так.

Comment: В таком случае вам "надо" сложить 2 и 2, получив 5. У объекта нет индексатора (откуда он там и что он должен вообще означать?), у него есть свойства Name, Type и Parent

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Можно же как-то создать массив на основе el.

Comment: Так что этот массив-то должен означать?

Comment: @Kir_Antipov он будет хранить один элемент списка. [0]индекс - Name ,[1] индекс - Type ,[2] индекс - Parent.

Comment: В чем тогда проблема? `var list = db.Query<dynamic>(...).Select(x => new object[] { x.Name, x.Type, x.Parent });`

Comment: `Query` возвращает коллекцию (IEnumerable). Вы по ней проходитесь циклом. Теперь обращайтесь к _свойствам_ `el`, не к индексатору.

Comment: Вместо `dynamic` укажите конкретный тип, с которым далее будет удобно работать. Этот тип должен иметь свойства, которые совпадают с полями в запросе: `Name` и т. д.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov В том то и дело что у меня нету этого типа.

Comment: @Kir_Antipov Спасибо, помогло. Напишите это решение в ответе, пожалуйста.

Comment: Я уже давно не пишу здесь ответы, так что можете дать самоответ с использованием моего комментария

Comment: Ну так создайте этот тип. Делов на одну минуту. | Или, раз уж используете dynamic, то работайте с его свойствами, не переводите их в массив.

Comment: @Kir_Antipov А как сделать тоже самое, но я не могу писать x.name из-за динамической базы?

Comment: Может, вам тогда не нужен Dapper-то? Используйте обычный ADO.NET и выгрузите данные в условный DataTable. А там уже есть индексаторы по индексу и по имени. Просто как бы какой смысл использовать фреймворк, если вам не нужны его возможности, и вы пытаетесь спуститься на более примитивный уровень?

Comment: @Kir_Antipov А есть решение с Dapper-ом?

Comment: Я не знаю, есть ли встроенное решение, так как никогда с ним не работал

Comment: А у вас прям база динамическая? Я не вижу в вопросе кода типа $"SELECT * FROM {table} Where {field} = 1" Вы откуда знаете, что в этой базе есть такая таблица с такими полями? Есть мнение, что либо вы упростили формулировку вопроса, убрав существенные подробности либо вам действительно стоит задуматься чтобы убрать Dapper - пользуйтесь ADO.

Answer (score 2):

Обычно когда используют Dapper то создают отдельный класс, а не гоняют в dynamic:

```
public class Tree
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Parent{ get; set; }
}
```

И не надо обращаться по индексу:

```
var List = db.Query<Tree>("SELECT Name, Type, Parent FROM TreeView Where Level = 1");
foreach (var element in List)
{
    MessageBox.Show(element.Name);
    MessageBox.Show(element.Type);
    MessageBox.Show(element.Parent);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Решение написал @Kir_Antipov:

```
var list = db.Query<dynamic>(...).Select(x => new object[] { x.Name, x.Type, x.Parent });
```

Comment: Это ответ рабочий, но плохой. Дал альтернативную версию ответа.

Comment: Почитал комментарии под ответом. Если это решение подходит лучше -- тогда вам лучше убрать Dapper совсем, раз вы не пользуетесь его фичами. Я так понимаю, вы тот автор который строит какой-то свой собственный инструмент для работы с произвольными базами и неизвестной структурой?